# Django example of a form that submits multiple instances into a database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need a django form that submits multiple separate requests, and can't find an example of how to do this without a lot of customization.  I.e., suppose there is a form that is used by a car repair shop.  The form will list all the possible repairs that the shop is capable of doing, and the user will select which repairs they want to have done (i.e., using checkboes.)

Each repair can be assigned to a different mechanic.  Each repair can also be cancelled or declared to be done, independent of the other repairs.   That seems to require that each repair become a separate instance in a database.

Additionally, each repair job can be only performed by certain mechanic. So I need the ability to associate each repair job to it's own unique list of mechanics to choose from.

Has anyone seen an example of a django form, that does something like this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/formsets/) (and [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)) are for.

Comment: Unfortunately, formsets are for generating multiple forms on a single page.  I'm looking for a single form that is capable of generating multiple instances.  My original post gives an example or why they need to be multiple instances, because the person needs to be able to specify each repair.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the question is asked and I had the same problem:

I solved it by instance = form.save(commit=False), then setting the different attributes, then instances.save(force_insert=True), then deleting the form.instance.id....

HOWEVER this means that all fields that are eventually overwritten in the save method stay after the frist call to save()... This bit me hard!

How did you end up doing it?